# Is to possible to prepare gallium oxide from gallium sulfate against gallium nitrate or ZnO from ZnSO4 against Zn(NO3)2

Tags: synthesis

Is it possible to synthesize Gallium oxide from Gallium sulfate? Usually I find gallium nitrate to be recommended. Similarly for ZnO synthesis, generally nitrate salt of zinc is preferred to sulfate salt. Why?

Comment: It is possible to synthesize everything from anything. What is your question, really?

Answer (score 1):

Generally gallium oxide is formed by decomposition of gallium salts. The choice of your gallium salt depends on decomposition temperature and cost of the salt. Gallium nitrate can be used for this purpose over gallium sulfate due of its low decomposition temperature.

\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathbf{Salt} & \mathbf{Decomposition~temperature}  & \mathbf{Cost (Sigma-Aldrich)}\\\hline
\text{Gallium sulfate} & \text{$\ce{>749°C}$} & \text{110 USD (5g)} \\
\text{Gallium nitrate} & \text{$\ce{200-250°C}$} & \text{$\ce{114 USD (5g)}$}\\\end{array}

Similarly goes for zinc where we would prefer the nitrate salt over sulfate.

\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathbf{Salt} & \mathbf{Decomposition~temperature}  & \mathbf{Cost (Sigma-Aldrich)}\\\hline
\text{Zinc sulfate} & \text{$\ce{>689°C}$} & \text{162.5 USD (1g)} \\
\text{Zinc nitrate} & \text{$\ce{>300°C}$} & \text{$\ce{26.2 USD (100g)}$}\\\end{array}

Note: although the decomposition side products are gaseous, they are both harmful to humans.

Comment: I think SO42- salts have higher disassociation temp because it has SO4 2- is more ionic than NO3-